# Need help in making exceptions to floating numbers

Tags: c++

When I enter floating numbers in the truck number..it goes straight to please enter weight then the corresponding statement if it is either ready to roll or it is over the limit..how do i correct this code so that only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are accepted and floating numbers will be invalid. thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE=8;
    bool isInputTruckInvalid(int inputTruck);
    bool isInputWeightNeg(float weight);
    int maxWeight[ARRAY_SIZE]={0,50000,25000,20000,35000,40000,25000,30000};
    int truckNum[ARRAY_SIZE]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int inputTruck;
    float weight;
    int choice();
    do
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the Truck Number: ";
        cin>>inputTruck;
    }
    while(isInputTruckInvalid(inputTruck));
    do
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the Weight: ";
        cin>>weight;    
    }while(isInputWeightNeg(weight));

    switch(truckNum[inputTruck])
    {
    case 1:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[1])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 1 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 1 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 50000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            if(weight<=maxWeight[2])
            {
                cout<<"Truck 2 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
                choice();
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Truck 2 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 25000"<<endl;
                choice();   
            }
            break;
    case 3:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[3])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 3 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 3 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 20000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[4])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 4 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 4 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 35000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[5])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 5 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 5 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 40000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[6])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 6 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 6 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 25000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[7])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 7 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 7 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 30000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isInputWeightNeg(float weight)
{
    if(weight<0)
    {
        cout<<"Weight is negative.Please input valid number."<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


bool isInputTruckInvalid(int inputTruck)
{
    if(inputTruck!=1 && inputTruck!=2  && inputTruck!=3  && inputTruck!=4  && inputTruck!=5  &&          inputTruck!=6 && inputTruck!=7 )
    {
        cout<<"You entered an invalid truck number."<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int choice()
{
    int retry;
    cout<<"\nDo you want to continue [Y/N]? 1 as yes/2 as No?:";
    cin>>retry;
    cout<<endl;
    switch (retry){
    case 1:
        main();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"Program terminated\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Invalid input";
        choice();
        break;
    }
    return retry;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of input that your current program accepts, but that you don't want it to?

Comment: Please enter the Truck Number: 5.5
Please enter the Weight: Truck is ready to roll- weight limit passed

Do you want to continue [Y/N]? 1 as yes/2 as No?:"// this is the  error, because it should be invalid when entering floating numbers

Comment: Please edit your original question so that you can format the output close to what it is when you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answer to your question, as your requirement is still not clear, even after reading your comment. But, please check the `main` function: 
What do you mean by the "`{`" after `case 2:` statement?

```
case 2:
        {
```

and the "`}`" just before `return 0;`

It should be

```
// --------------
    case 2:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[2])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 2 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 2 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 25000"<<endl;
            choice();   
        }
        break;

/// ----------------
    case 7:
        if(weight<=maxWeight[7])
        {
            cout<<"Truck 7 is ready to roll - weight limit passed"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Truck 7 has exceeded the maximum allowable weight limit of 30000"<<endl;
            choice();
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the function `isInputTruckInvalid` so complicated? 
It can be a simple range check between 1 and 7 instead of so many `&&` and `!=`

Thirdly, don't call `main()` from `choice()` - there are better ways to keep the program running.

Comment: i mistyped the "{" in case 2 and do you have suggestions for keeping the program running without using choice. The point of the program is that there are 7 trucks, you input either 1-7.. i want floating numbers to be invalid except 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0..7.0.